# ¿Cómo conectar la cámara de un ESP32 Wrover (Wifi Cam)?

Tags: c++, arduino, cámara, esp8266, esp32

he compilado este código en Arduino, WiFi Cam Example

```
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include "esp_system.h"
#include <esp32cam.h>

static auto HQVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(240, 160);  
static auto QVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(320, 240);
static auto WQVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(400, 240);  
static auto VGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(640, 480);  
static auto SVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(800, 600);

const char *ssid = "***";
const char *password = "***";
const char *dns = "camara";

WebServer servidor(80);


void conectaWiFi(){

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connectando a la red: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.persistent(false); //Permite que la configuracion del Wifi no sea afectada.
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);    //Configura el Wifi en modo estacion
    WiFi.begin(ssid,password);      
 
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);       
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi conectado");
    Serial.println("Direccion IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println("Direccion MAC: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
    //http://camara.local   //Servidor dns que sustituye a la IP (solo funciona con 
    Linux o IOS) Para windows se requiere software adicional

    if (!MDNS.begin(dns)) {
          Serial.print("Se configuro el DNS: http://");
          Serial.print(dns);
          Serial.println(".local/");

    }
    else{
        MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80); 
    } 

}

void error404() {
    servidor.send(200, "text/plain", "Error pagina no encontrada");  
}

void servirImagen() {

  auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
  if (frame == nullptr) {
    servidor.send(503, "", "");

    return;
  }
   Serial.printf("IMAGEN TOMADA %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(),
                static_cast<int>(frame->size()));

  servidor.setContentLength(frame->size());
  servidor.send(200, "image/jpeg");
  WiFiClient client = servidor.client();
  frame->writeTo(client);
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  using namespace esp32cam;

  Config configuracion;
  configuracion.setPins(pins::AiThinker);
  configuracion.setResolution(QVGA);
  configuracion.setBufferCount(5);  //Establece el numero de imagenes en el buffer
  configuracion.setJpeg(80);

  bool ok = Camera.begin(configuracion); //Inicializa la camara con la configuracion         
  previa
  Serial.println(ok ? "CAMERA OK" : "Error al inicializar la camara");

  conectaWiFi();

  servidor.on("/imagen.jpg", servirImagen); //En la funcion servirImagenes se creara la 
  pagina /imagen.jpg

  servidor.onNotFound(error404);

  servidor.begin();

  Serial.println("Servidor iniciado");

  }

void loop() {
  servidor.handleClient();
}
```

El código anterior se compila sin problemas, pero el acceso a la cámara se muestra como fallido, verifiqué el código de error pero todavía no funciona, la información de la red WiFi y la contraseña están ingresadas de manera correcta (En el código de aqui lo saqué por razones de seguridad), pero el fallo está en vincularse con la cámara ya que incluso me brinda la IP para ingresarla al navegador.

[image: Imagen del error]

En el Arduino IDE está establecido con estas configuraciones:

[image: Configuraciones del Arduino IDE]

Este es mi ESP32:

[image: ESP32]

Comment: Existe [MicroPython](https://micropython.org), una versión de Python que corre en una variedad de MCU (ESP8266, ESP32, ...)

Comment: Pues por lo que se ve en el log, estás configurando la cámara antes de levantar la red ... deberías hacerlo al revés